# "Governs should increase as much of the expenditure on public services as possible."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

For example:

> Governs should increase as much of the expenditure on public services as possible.

Would it be correct?

Comment: That quoted text does not make sense to me. What is "governs" in this example? Is: '*Government* should *direct* as much of the expenditure *as possible* on public services.' what you are trying to express?

Comment: Are you asking if you can put something in between the "as much" and the "as possible"? You should try to clarify what you are really asking about.

Comment: Yes ..I mean that .. If i can put someting in between the "as much" and the "as possible" when I'm writing an essay ?

Comment: _Governs_ is not a noun. You probably mean _government_, but I suppose you might mean _governments_.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean "governments". Anyway, when you write:

> Governments should increase **as much of the expenditure** on public services as possible.

*much* refers to some quantity of the expenditures. However in

> Governments should increase (the expenditures on public services) **as much as possible**.

*much* refers to the possibility/chances of increases happening, but not the amount of such expenditures. To make this clearer, you could rephrase it:

> Governments should increase **as much as possible** (the expenditures on public services).

I would avoid splitting up "as much as possible" without a specific reason, as it will be more difficult to understand correctly, especially in speech.

Answer (score 0):

(Replacing governs, a verb, by governments, a noun)

*To me*, the **most natural way of saying this** would be:

> 1. Governments should increase expenditure on public services as much as possible.

Even though there is a very slight ambiguity there in whether "much" is referring to the "expenditure" or the "likelihood of the increase", I do not find the other options quite as natural. Especially if you write it this way:

> 2. Governments should increase as much of the expenditure on public services as possible.

it seems to imply a very specific reference to a *percentage* or *fractional increase* ('as much of the expenditure'), while statement 1 is more flexible with what kind of a change it is. **Mathematically, the two differ**, and thus I would prefer/suggest 1. Compared to 2, I could see this statement working better:

> 3. Governments should increase as much expenditure on public services as possible.

but it may sound better or worse than 1 to different people. I guess you could go with 1 or 3. Statement 2 is grammatically correct, but mathematically may not mean what you want it to say. Of course, if that is what you had in mind, though, then 2 (your original statement) works best.